# El Capitan beta - VirtualBox 5 won't open: Effective UID is not root

Tags: macos, virtualbox

I had VB 4.3 running on OSX El Capitan betas 1-3. I installed VB 5 and it doesn't launch and gives the message Effective UID is not root.

I found the post at [VirtualBox does not start on Mac OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/620936/virtualbox-does-not-start-on-mac-os-x). The method posted by Deborah Speece works for starting it via Terminal but the post from realityloop broke it again and I needed to reinstall.

Does anyone have a way to launch VB 5 from the app icon in OSX El Capitan?

---

I just installed VirtualBox 5 on OSX Yosemite with no problems. This problem seems to be specific to El Capitan which in in beta. Hopefully it will be resoled in the supported version.

I also have a work-around by using an Automator workflow app with some scripts.

Comment: Same issue here. Same for VB 4.2.*, 4.3.* and 5. I hope we will get our answers. I reported the bug on several channels, so if we find something I'll share it with you here too.

Answer (score 6):

I have successfully solved the problem.

First you must want to remove the application with [AppCleaner](http://www.freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/) (`brew cask install appcleaner`). Here is my terminal log after that. Using [homebrew](http://brew.sh) for installations.

```bash
rm -rf ~/VirtualBox\ VMs ~/Library/VirtualBox
brew cask uninstall virtualbox
brew cask install virtualbox
for bin in VirtualBox VirtualBoxVM VBoxNetAdpCtl VBoxNetDHCP VBoxNetNAT VBoxHeadless; do
    sudo chmod u+s "/Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/${bin}"
done
```

Comment: May need `brew tap phinze/homebrew-cask && brew install brew-cask` if you do not already have it setup.

Answer (score 0):

I installed the OSX El capitan and I cannot open my VB, so i download and reinstalled the last version the virtualbox (his apps too) and my vb started. I don't have idea but it worked.